# Como marcar próxima checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

A partir da seleção atual da checkbox, como marcar o próximo elemento checkbox e desativar todas as outras.

tenho esse código, que ao marcar uma checkbox consequentemente todas as outras são desativadas, mas preciso que ao marcar uma checkbox automaticamente ela marque a próxima checkbox e desative as outras.

Tentei com o next() mas não obtive sucesso

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#formNine input:checkbox').click(function(){

var $inputs = $('#formNine input:checkbox')

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); // <-- disable all but checked one
    }else{
       $inputs.prop('disabled',false); // <--
    }

});
```

});

Comment: Tem de explicar melhor o que quer fazer. Quer marcar a próxima checkbox ou a que foi clicada? Quer fazer `disabled`? Isto depende também da estrutura do HTML. Pode colocar aqui um exemplo do seu HTML?

Comment: O seu código, adaptado, dá isto: http://jsfiddle.net/zLu25z45/ que é basicamente o que um radio button faz... Quero ajudar mas não percebo o que quer.

Comment: por exemplo tenho um <label><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></label> se eu marcar a primeira quero que fique marcado a primeira e a segunda, se eu marcar a segunda que fique marcado a segunda e terceira, sempre que marcar uma checkbox, marcar também a próximo, entende ? acho que agora deu pra me expressar melhor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dá pra fazer com `next()`.

Adiciona no final do `if`:

`$(this).next().prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', false);`

Ficando assim:

```
if($(this).is(':checked')){
   $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); // <-- disable all but checked one
   $(this).next().prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', false);
}else{
   $inputs.prop('disabled',false); // <--
}
```

Comment: perfeito, agora só falta quando eu desmarcar o atual desmarcar o next() que ele marcou. Mas é exatamente isso. Desculpem não sou muito bom em jQuery

Comment: Pronto ficou assim:if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); // <-- disable all but checked one
     $(this).next().prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', false);
  }else{
     $inputs.prop('disabled',false); // <--
     $(this).next().prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true);
  }